# How to call an Interstitial by clicking on an item in the list that goes through an Adapter?

Tags: java, android

I need to call an Interstitial in this Activity by clicking on an item in the list that comes from my Adapter.

```
public class SoundRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SoundRecyclerAdapter.SoundViewHolder> {
    private final ArrayList<SoundObject> soundObjects;

    SoundRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<SoundObject> soundObjects) {
        this.soundObjects = soundObjects;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SoundViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sound_item, parent, false);
        return new SoundViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SoundViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final SoundObject object = soundObjects.get(position);
        final Integer soundID = object.getItemID();

        holder.itemTextView.setText(object.getItemName());
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // I tried calling the interstitial here, but to no avail
                EventHandlerClass.startMediaPlayer(v, soundID);
            }
        });

        // Handle actions when the user presses a sound button
        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                EventHandlerClass.popupManager(v, object);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return soundObjects.size();
    }

    class SoundViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final TextView itemTextView;

        SoundViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What was your error?

Comment: I tried calling an Interstitial with the same code as MainActivity in the adapter's OnClick. However, I'm not able to find the context (in case MainActivit is "this").

Comment: I think your problem is resolved now. Please accept the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Pass context as parameter of adapter's constructor:

```
private Context context;

SoundRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SoundObject> soundObjects) {
    this.soundObjects = soundObjects;
    this.context = context;
}
```

and use it in click handler

Comment: I made the implementation on the adapter. However, another problem has arisen in MainActiviy. I get an error in "soundList", suggesting my options: create constructor or remove parametrix from SoundRecyclerAdapter.

private final SoundRecyclerAdapter SoundAdapter = new SoundRecyclerAdapter (soundList);

Comment: Replace instantiation with `SoundAdapter = new SoundRecyclerAdapter(this, soundList);`

Comment: It worked! I just made a small change by reversing "this, songList" to "soundList, this". Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @RodolfoOliveira, glad to be of help

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in the `setOnClickListener()` method:

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(SoundRecyclerAdapter.this);
```

Then add the adrequests and load the ad.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the implementation of S-Sh worked perfectly!

Comment: That's the same work done in two different ways. I did with less code.